# Publishing erratum to arXiv and other best practices

Tags: journals, copyright, arxiv, errors-erratum

Is publishing a single page erratum to arXiv an acceptable practice? And does it violate the copyright of journal who published the original work?

Comment: An erratum _is_ an original work.  The copyright to the original article applies only to the original article.

Comment: The webpage of the article which is corrected by the erratum should point to the erratum on arXiv.

Comment: Is there a reason not to do erratum or corrigendum through the journal? That would be the best in that they also show up as links when someone looks at the article coming in from looking at citations from another paper, or from a subject search on line. (Of course, one can also note it in arXiv for people who are accessing the article there).

Comment: Is there a point not to make the erratum in the arXiv preprint, making it a consolidated, up-to-date version?

Comment: @Carol journal denied the request as the error is minor in nature. By mistake in 2 steps of a formula derivation  I changed denominator to numerator. I believe it is not a minor mistake and should not be ignored, but editor insisted that final equation is correct and reader can understand that it is just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Has the original paper been posted on the arXiv?

If so, I suggest updating it with a corrected version, and communicating **clearly** in the Comments field that this new version is a corrected one. (Also, I'd change the Journal-Ref to indicate that it doesn't exactly correspond to the publication.)

In terms of copyright, this *may* be in a grey zone in case you've signed away the rights to your preprint to the publisher. But if so, it is a grey zone academics have been comfortably treading for years.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not exactly an objective answer for your question, but it's the closest I could find by now (a feedback in the comments so we can improve it later would be great).

The problem in doing so is that people searching for your research may find the original one and not find the erratum. In that case, your goal of getting people to know your typo would fail.

About the copyright, laws may change from country to country, so it's hard to determine. Yet, if you somehow include a large amount of the published work it's likely a copyright violation. If it's not the case, just a small part, I don't think it would be a problem.

Finally, It's not the most appropriate form of proceeding. I know the editor refused to fix it, as you said in comments, but once you submitted to that journal you have kinda agreed that the journal's editor is the best one to make this kind of decisions. So, I would follow the editor even if I disagreed (and in that case I totally disagree).